# Concatenating two dictionaries together

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am very confused as to how to solve the issue, since I run into a lot of errors such as such as `TypeError: string indices must be integers.`

Given:

```
dmx={'a': 0, 'b': 3, 'c': 9, 'd': 2, 'e': 4}
dx={'a': 2, 'b': 4, 'c': 9, 'd': 5, 'e': 1}
```

I want to produce:

```
d={'a': [2,0], 'b': [4,3], 'c': [9,9], 'd': [5,2] ,'e': [1,4]}
```

Comment: what if there is a key which is present in dmx but not in dx?

Comment: I will not be running into this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a generic solution for any number of dictionaries, you can use `setdefault`:

```
out = {}
for d in [dmx, dx]:
    for k,v in d.items():
        out.setdefault(k, list()).append(v)
```

Or use [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
from collections import defaultdict

out = defaultdict(list)

for d in [dmx, dx]:
    for k,v in d.items():
        out.append(v)
```

Output:

```
{'a': [0, 2], 'b': [3, 4], 'c': [9, 9], 'd': [2, 5], 'e': [4, 1]}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```py
{k: [v1, v2] for k, v1, v2 in zip(dmx.keys(), dmx.values(), dx.values())}
```

---

If the keys aren't in the same order in both dictionaries (since dictionaries are insertion-ordered in Python 3.7+), then you can use the following instead:

```py
{k: [dmx[k], dx[k]] for k in dmx.keys()}
```

Both of these output:

```py
{'a': [0, 2], 'b': [3, 4], 'c': [9, 9], 'd': [2, 5], 'e': [4, 1]}
```